# How To Update Mysql Database After Clicking Button With Link?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using following code to open a url through *fancybox*. I want to update *mysql* database when user clicks on this button.

current code is :

```
 <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" href="http://www.google.com">
 <button style="cursor:pointer; padding:8px;">Test Live Session</button></a>
```

I want to update mysql database when user clicks on button along with opening the url in fancybox.

mysql update is as below

```
mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET test_session_clicked='1' 
WHERE reg_id=".$_SESSION['user_id21']");
```

Comment: just use the button to submit the form or use ajax if you do not want to refresh the page

Comment: Would usually be done with javascript, so on button [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) you [fire off a request](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to server side (php) that runs the query.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_` functions. They have been deprecated. You should look into migrating over to `mysqli_` or PDO. And your code is likely to be prone to SQL injection. Meanwhile, the technology you are asking to bridge the gap is called AJAX — you use JS to make an AJAX call to a server script that executes your query and (optionally) returns a response.

Comment: ok...but how to use a href class in header in Ajax where we r using the url ?

Comment: You want use jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe more_info_btn" href="http://www.google.com">
<button style="cursor:pointer; padding:8px;" id="btn">Test Live Session</button></a>



 jQuery('#btn').click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'your Php file path',
         data:{'updated':true},
         dataType:'json'
         success:function(data){
          alert(data.error);
         }
    })
    })
```

php file your

```
    if (isset($_POST['updated'])){

   $queryStr = "UPDATE tablename SET test_session_clicked='1' 
    WHERE reg_id=".$_SESSION['user_id21'];
    if ( mysql_query($qyeryStr)){
         echo json_encode(array('error'=>false));
    }else{
         echo json_encode(array('error'=>true));
     }
    }
```

Comment: your test_session_clicked filed type is intager?

Comment: you get ajax response?

Comment: i didin't get your point... test_session_cliked is a column in database with type tinyint

Comment: Use this query  $queryStr = "UPDATE tablename SET test_session_clicked=1 
    WHERE reg_id=".$_SESSION['user_id21'];